# Correlation of Multiple values in a single regular expression

Tags: loadrunner

I have to capture entity id and entity name in a single regular expression shown below:-

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=SelectedHub",
     "RegExp=entityId\":(.*?),\"entityName\":\"(.*?)\"",
      SEARCH_FILTERS,
     "Scope=Body",
     "IgnoreRedirections=No",
     "Group=0",
     "Ordinal=all",
      LAST);
```

Response:-

> Action.c(32): Notify: Saving Parameter "SelectedHub_1 = entityId":1,"entityName":"Product"".
>   Action.c(32): Notify: Saving Parameter "SelectedHub_2 = entityId":3,"entityName":"Package"".
>   Action.c(32): Notify: Saving Parameter "SelectedHub_3 = entityId":2,"entityName":"Crop"".

I want to use it similar to jmeter as `SelectedHub_1`  for entity id and `SelectedHub_2` for entity name. Please can anyone let me know how to achieve thi

Answer (score 1):

You can use two regular expressions one for "EntityID" and second one for "EntityName"

Say you will get the output as below:
EntityID: IDParam_1, IDParam_2,..
EntityName: NameParam_1, NameParam_2,..

You can get the random ID related to Name vise versa by using below simple c logic:

`int i, pcount, count = 0, result;

char tmpParamID[50], tmpParamName[50], FinalParamName[50];

```
        pcount = atoi(lr_eval_string("{IDParam_count}")); 

        for(i = 1; i<= pcount; i++){
                    sprintf(tmpParamID, "{IDParam_%d}", i);
                    result = strcmp(lr_eval_string(tmpParamID), lr_eval_string("{RequiredID}"));
                    if(result == 0){
                                count = i;
                                break;
                    }                        
        }
```

sprintf(tmpParamName, "{NameParam_%d}",count);

lr_save_string(lr_eval_string(tmpParamName),"FinalParamName");`

Here "RequiredID" will be the "EntityID" for which you want "EntityName"

Answer (score 0):

You need to duplicate the call with two different parameter names and have the Group value set to 1 in the first call and 2 in the second call.
Please see the documentation of "web_reg_save_param_regexp" Groups section

Comment: I agree, we can use two different parameter names, but when we select random number it will pick one value for "parameter1" and another value for "parameter2" again which will not match.

Comment: You have an option to "link" parameters in the parameters properties window. There is a combobox called "Select next row", you should have an option there to link it with another parameter

Comment: Yes, that we can do in parameters created through parameterisation but these are correlated parameter values. These will not display in parameter properties window. So how we can achieve this.